# How to organize groups in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am currently learning how to use Django. I want to make a web app where you as a user can join groups. These groups have content that just members of this group should be able to see. I learned about users, groups and a bit of authentication.

My first impression is, that this is more about the administration of the website itself and I cannot really believe that I can solve my idea with it.

I just want to know if thats the way to go in Django. I probably have to create groups in Django that have the right to see the content of the group on the website. But that means that everytime a group is created, I have to create a django group. Is that an overkill or the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Groups in django (django.contrib.auth) are used to specify certain rights of viewing content mainly in the admin to certain users. I think your group functionality might be more custom than this and that you're better of creating your own group models, and making your own user and group management structure that suits the way your website is used better.